# Slow rsync from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, server-message-block, cifs

I backup files using rsync from RHEL Linux to Windows 10 Pro using SMB/CIFS share. It works fine except it is much slower than Linux to Linux. Both computers are fairly modern Dell OptiPlex, having 6-core CPUs, 16GB memory, NVMe disks, 1 GigE NICs. Linux top utility does not show any bottleneck on CPU/memory/IO, screenshot attached. Where else could be the bottleneck?
[image: top-cpu-mem-io usage]

Answer (score 1):

When syncing to a SMB/CIFS share `rsync` needs to read the whole share to compare the files...

You should run a `rsync` daemon on windows to let it do the comparison of the files.
This will speed things up.

In Cygwin you can install `rsync` and `cygrunsrv` package.
To install as a service: `cygrunsrv.exe -I rsync -p /bin/rsync -a "--daemon --no-detach"`

Comment: Agree, that will help. However, without running rsync daemon, I should see high i/o and CPU usage, which is not the case.